# OpenCV VideoCaptures sometimes returns blank frames

Tags: c++, opencv, video, capture

I am using the following code for capturing video frames from a USB webcam using openCV3 in MS VC++ 2012. But the problem is that sometimes I am able to display the captured frames @ 30 fps but sometimes I get black frames with a very low fps (or with a high delay). In other words, the program works randomly. Do you know how I can solve this problem? I tried different solutions suggested in stackoverflow or some other places but none of them solved the problem.

```
VideoCapture v(1);
v.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 720);
v.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
if(!v.isOpened()){
   cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << endl;
   return;
}

Mat Image;
namedWindow("win",1);

while(1){
    v >> Image;
    imshow("win", Image);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
while(1){
    v >> Image;
    imshow("win", Image);
    char c=waitKey(10);//add a 10ms delay per frame to sync with cam fps
    if(c=='b')
       {
            break;//break when b is pressed
       }
}
```